# How do I handle many images in my HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm very new to Html5 canvas and Javascript. I'm trying this :

```
function animate() {    
   var image1 = new Image();
   image.src = /path
   var image2 = new Image();
   image2.src = /path
   for(;;)
   {
        //change value of x and y so that it looks like moving
        context.beginPath();
        context.drawImage(<image>, x, y );
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
   }
}
```

### EDIT:

And I call the `animate` function each 33ms :

```
if (playAnimation) {
            // Run the animation loop again in 33 milliseconds
            setTimeout(animate, 33);
        };
```

If I follow the answer given here, I get the image **struck** and its not moving any further.

Comment: Do you want to draw them all to the same location (in succession) or do you want to draw them all to different locations? More details are needed to really help you.

Comment: OK, edited my answer with details for that, then.

Comment: And where do you want the images to move? Randomly? In a line? In separate predetermined paths?

Comment: @Phrogz: I will calculating the value for `x` and `y` in my for loop. It will be moving in a circular path ..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update**: Based on new information in the question, your problem (restated) is that you want to either

1. wait for all images to load first, and *then* start animating with them, or
2. start animating and only use an image if it is available.

Both are described below.

### 1. Loading many images and proceeding only when they are finished

With this technique we load all images immediately and when the last has loaded we run a custom callback.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3MPrT/1/

```js
// Load images and run the whenLoaded callback when all have loaded;
// The callback is passed an array of loaded Image objects.
function loadImages(paths,whenLoaded){
  var imgs=[];
  paths.forEach(function(path){
    var img = new Image;
    img.onload = function(){
      imgs.push(img);
      if (imgs.length==paths.length) whenLoaded(imgs);
    }
    img.src = path;
  });
}

var imagePaths = [...]; // array of strings
loadImages(imagePaths,function(loadedImages){
  setInterval(function(){ animateInCircle(loadedImages) }, 30);
});
```

### 2. Keeping track of all images loaded so far

With this technique we start animating immediately, but only draw images once they are loaded. Our circle dynamically changes dimension based on how many images are loaded so far.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3MPrT/2/

```js
var imagePaths = [...]; // array of strings
var loadedImages = [];  // array of Image objects loaded so far

imagePaths.forEach(function(path){
  // When an image has loaded, add it to the array of loaded images
  var img = new Image;
  img.onload = function(){ loadedImages.push(img); }
  img.src = path;
});

setInterval(function(){
  // Only animate the images loaded so far
  animateInCircle(loadedImages);
}, 100);
```

*And, if you wanted the images to rotate in a circle instead of just move in a circle:*

#### Rotating images: http://jsfiddle.net/3MPrT/7/

```js
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(cx,cy); // Center of circle
ctx.rotate( (angleOffset+(new Date)/3000) % Math.TAU );
ctx.translate(radius-img.width/2,-img.height/2);
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
ctx.restore();
```

---

*Original answer follows.*

In general, you must wait for each image loading to complete:

```
function animate(){
  var img1 = new Image;
  img1.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(img1,x1,y1);
  };
  img1.src = "/path";

  var img2 = new Image;
  img2.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(img2,x2,y2);
  };
  img2.src = "/path";
}
```

You may want to make this code more DRY by using an object:

```
var imgLocs = {
  "/path1" : { x:17, y:42  },
  "/path2" : { x:99, y:131 },
  // as many as you want
};

function animate(){
  for (var path in imgLocs){
    (function(imgPath){
      var xy = imgLocs[imgPath];
      var img = new Image;
      img.onload = function(){
        context.drawImage( img, xy.x, xy.y );
      }
      img.src = imgPath;
    })(path);
  }
}
```

Comment: To preempt comments regarding `hasOwnProperty()` I offer [my opinion on why it is no longer appropriate](http://phrogz.net/death-to-hasownproperty).

Comment: I'm trying animating here. Inside the `for` by changing `x` and `y`.So I guess this solution doesn't work here. As it is getting strucked for next iteration of for loop!. I tried `image1.onload = \function(){
        context.drawImage(image1,tmpAsteroid.x,tmpAsteroid.y );
     };` This inside my for loop.

Comment: @batman You need to edit your question with more information on what you want to do during "animation". You are not providing enough information to help.